# R user function column name selection with or without quotes

Tags: dplyr, user-defined-functions, quotes, r-colnames

I want to be able to enter a column name of a tibble in a user function with or without using quotation marks.  Using myfunc function below I can enter the column name, but I can't encapsulate it within "".  Is there a way to use both methods in a single user-defined function?

```
myfunc <- function(dat, col1){
  dat %>%
    mutate(col2 = {{ col1 }}+1)
}
# ok
myfunc(iris, Sepal.Length)

# error
myfunc(iris, "Sepal.Length")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.name` and `substitute` to convert your character variable to an unquoted variable, and at the same time not change a variable that is already unquoted:

```r
myfunc <- function(dat, col1){
  col1 <- as.name(substitute(col1))
  dat %>%
    mutate(col2 = {{col1}} + 1)
}
```

output

```r
all.equal(myfunc(iris, Sepal.Length), 
          myfunc(iris, "Sepal.Length"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great. thanks for that Mael.  Any idea how to handle more than 1 column at a time?  I tried using map_df(c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), ~myfunc(iris, .x)) but an error occurred
"Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `col2 = .x + 1`.
Caused by error:
! object '.x' not found"